# How do I fix the problem with objects getting overwrite?

Tags: c#, class, oop

When I create some students, subjects and try to add a grade to a specific student on any subject then all students have that grade on that subject, why is this happening? I tried to separate them because I need every grade on a student subject to be unique from the others but I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

```
class Student
{
    string name;
    string surname;
    int studentID;
    public List<Subject> subjectList = new List<Subject>();
}

class Subject 
{ 
    string name;
    int subjectID;
    public List<int> grades = new List<int>();
}
```

Comment: The class definitions look fine, how are you using them?

Comment: You should have a `List` in the `Student` class called `Grades` that references the subject ID and the grade.

Comment: Please show the code where you initialize the students, so we can see where it's going wrong. Most likely you're re-using the same instance of `Subject` for multiple students, so when the grades are changed for one, they're changed for all.

Comment: The problem is I wrote the code on my language and I don't know if it's good to post the code here and provide a translation about some words

Comment: @TheHamshah When you assign Subjects to the student, use "ToList()" to create a copy of the subjects instead of creating a reference.

Comment: @TheHamshah put a better title , your question title doesn't address your problem.

Comment: @TheHamshah seeing code in another language is better than seeing no code. The objects in the framework do not change language, only your variable names.

Comment: Can I send the code on the comment section cause the post it's closed due to title and I can't post as answer

Comment: You can edit the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C# classes are reference types which means that objects instantiated from a class are actually references to an object which lives on the heap.

This issue happened to me a long time ago when I began working with classes. Finally I found that I did not instantiate classes well.

You've not shown you code in order to fix and explain your code, but I am sure that your problem is due to bad re-using a reference to the same object.

For example, below is an example of reusing the same object references. All objects within the `List<MyClass>` will have value of `9` because `myClass` points to a single object in memory rather than instantiating 9 instances of `MyClass`.

```cs
MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
List<MyClass> allClasses = new List<MyClass>();
for(int i =0 ; i < 10 ; i++)
{
   myClass.Value = i;
   allClasses.add(myClass);
}
public class MyClass{public int Value =0 ;}
```

But correct one is, in the below, we are instantiating new objects with references to those objects instead of using pointing to a single allocation on the heap

```cs
List<MyClass> allClasses = new List<MyClass>();
for(int i =0 ; i < 10 ; i++)
{
   MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
   myClass.Value = i;
   allClasses.add(myClass);
}
public class MyClass{public int Value =0 ;}
```

Hope I would be clear and correct.

Read more about [reference types here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types)

Comment: C# is not reference type, classes are reference types while structs are value types.

Comment: @ColinM definitely yeah. i mean the main idea of C#,You can correct me .

Comment: That's a good explanation,thank u very much I needed it

Comment: @TheHamshah did i explained you clearly ?

Comment: @Mr.AF Yea it's great

Comment: @ColinM thanks , you enriched it well.

Comment: @TheHamshah don't forget to mark this as the answer if it solves your problem

Comment: @ColinM I will.